# How to format cells in specific column of an ng-repeat table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, semantic-ui

I have a table and the last column is overflowing off the page. It's just one line that overflows over the right edge of the page and keeps extending, but you can't see it or scroll through it. I am using semantic ui framework.

How can I contain the text within the bounds of each cell of ONLY the last column? I'm not sure how to approach it because I  need to use ng-repeat to produce table data.

I tried adding `ng-style="overflow:scroll; max-width:300px"` to my `<td></td>` tags, but it's applying a scrollable overflowed cell for every single cell in the table.

```
<table class="ui left aligned red table"
                ng-show="ishowError">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th ng-repeat="head in headers"
                            ng-bind="ifixHeader(headers[$index])"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr
                        ng-repeat="nfo in allError | filter:dashFilter">
                        <td ng-repeat="head in headers"
                            ng-bind="nfo[headers[$index]]">
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the 'last-child' selector? Add this to your CSS.

```
    tr td:last-child{
          overflow:scroll;
          max-width:300px;
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Do you know how I can only have scroll overflow for text of certain length? I now have grey blocks around cells that don't even overflow.